# How do I go about creating a Ribbon component in QT?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, pyside2, qqmlcomponent

A Ribbon is the following component:
 [image: A Ribbon]

I would like to build the component using QtQuick (QML) and PySide2 as backend.

---

Current Solutions I have taught:
I know I can build the buttons using a TopBar, i.e:
 [image: The Top Button group of ribbon]

I can create three different delegates for the three different types of button:

Delegate 1:

[image]

Delegate 2:

[image]

Delegate 3:

[image]

And change them by specifying as a "type" in model.

### ---------------------------------------------------------

But how do I put them together?
I have taught about:
•   ListView can have only one orientation, so I am not able to build it using that.
•   Grid View, but it also has the same problem of one orientation possible.

Can someone please give me an idea of how can I build the ribbon component? How should the model be specified?

How Can I add the button grouper at the bottom, i.e:
 [image]

It should automatically expand as per number of buttons in the group.

Comment: Try playing around with a plain repeater? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html

Comment: Could you please brief me a little about the repeater approach? @hyde

Answer (score 2):

Let me briefly put what you can do here.

1. create separate items (.qml files) for `slides`, `fonts` and `paragraphs`. It creates separation of concern.
2. arrange those items you created in 1st step in a parent item, which just joins them together through anchoring or may be jus inside a `row`.
3. Now for each item design. Lets take the example of `slides`

Here you can arrange the items in two rows, second row will contain `slides` and first row will contain rest of the items.

now the first row can be divided into two columns
1st column -> `new slide`
2nd column -> `layout`, `reset`, `section` (here if you have similar items you can just use repeater)

Basically its the same kind of design for `font` and `paragraph`. You divide them as rows and columns and fit your items in them.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a great approach, I will try this.
Could you please brief me how could I make this dynamic?
For eg: I want to have a Model for "Slides" as:
{Name: "New Slide", icon: "\u1586", delegate: "BigButton{}", action: "a.launch()"}
and so on...
Given this, it should dynamically generate it...
------
Which is better : 
the above dynamic approach or the Static approach you suggested?